# Open Cart: Custom Modules are Not appearing in the Site

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I am new with the Opencart and I was trying to implement a custom module. I able to add them in the Extension https://prnt.sc/3zYnLR3_bqM6. Added the following module in the homepage layout to see if its working https://prnt.sc/UNx6dtTc7p9L. Currently it is not showing the custom section.

I tried to recheck the codes, do not know if its right as I followed most of tutorials I've seen in the YT and open cart related forums . Still unsuccessful with the workarounds. Want to know how to make it appear in the website.

Here are my codes in case:

Admin >> Controller:

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleTestSection extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Do note that below are the sample for using module helper, you may use it in other modules
        $array = array(
            'oc' => $this,
            'heading_title' => 'Test Section',
            'modulename' => 'test_section',
            'fields' => array(
                array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Title', 'name' => 'title'),
                array('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'First Section Description', 'name' => 'first_section_description','ckeditor'=>true),
                array('type' => 'repeater', 'label' => 'First Section Logos', 'name' => 'first_section_logos',
                    'fields' => array(
                        array('type' => 'image', 'label' => 'Logos', 'name' => 'image'),
                    )),

                array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Second Section Title', 'name' => 'second_section_title'),
                array('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'Second Section Description 1', 'name' => 'second_section_description_1','ckeditor'=>true),
                array('type' => 'repeater', 'label' => 'Second Section Logos', 'name' => 'second_section_logos',
                    'fields' => array(
                        array('type' => 'image', 'label' => 'Logos', 'name' => 'image'),
                         array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Title', 'name' => 'title'),
                    )),
                array('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'Second Section Description 2', 'name' => 'second_section_description_2','ckeditor'=>true),
                
                array('type' => 'image', 'label' => 'Third Section Vision Image', 'name' => 'third_section_vision_image'),
                array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Third Section Vision Title', 'name' => 'third_section_vision_title'),
                array('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'Third Section Vision Statement', 'name' => 'third_section_vision_statement','ckeditor'=>true),
                array('type' => 'image', 'label' => 'Third Section Mission Image', 'name' => 'third_section_mission_image'),
                array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Third Section Mission Title', 'name' => 'third_section_mission_title'),
                array('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'Third Section Mission Statement', 'name' => 'third_section_mission_statement','ckeditor'=>true),
                array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Third Section Value Statement Title', 'name' => 'third_section_value_statement_title'),
                array('type' => 'repeater', 'label' => 'Third Section Logos', 'name' => 'third_section_logos',
                    'fields' => array(
                        array('type' => 'image', 'label' => 'Logos', 'name' => 'image'),
                        array('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'Description', 'name' => 'description','ckeditor'=>true),
                    )),
                
               array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Fourth Section Title', 'name' => 'fourth_section_title'),
               array('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'Fourth Section Description', 'name' => 'fourth_section_description','ckeditor'=>true),
               array('type' => 'repeater', 'label' => 'Fourth Section Logos', 'name' => 'fourth_section_logos',
                    'fields' => array(
                        array('type' => 'image', 'label' => 'Logos', 'name' => 'image'),
                        array('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'Description', 'name' => 'description','ckeditor'=>true),
                    )),
            ),
        );

        $this->modulehelper->init($array);    
    }
}
```

Catalog >> Controller:

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleTestSection extends Controller {
public function index($setting) {
    $oc = $this;
    $language_id = $this->config->get('config_language_id');
    $modulename = 'test_section';
    $this->load->library('modulehelper');

    $Modulehelper = Modulehelper::get_instance($this->registry);
    $data = array(
        'title' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'title' ),
        'first_section_description' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'first_section_description' ),
        'first_section_logos' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'first_section_logos' ),
        
        
        'second_section_title' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'second_section_title' ),
        'second_section_description_1' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'second_section_description_1' ),
        'second_section_logos' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'second_section_logos' ),
        'second_section_description_2' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'second_section_description_2' ),

        'third_section_vision_title' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'third_section_vision_title' ),
        'third_section_vision_image' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'third_section_vision_image' ),
        'third_section_vision_statement' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'third_section_vision_statement' ),
        'third_section_mission_title' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'third_section_mission_title' ),
        'third_section_mission_image' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'third_section_mission_image' ),
        'third_section_mission_statement' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'third_section_mission_statement' ),
        'third_section_value_statement_title' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'third_section_value_statement_title' ),
        'third_section_logos' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'third_section_logos' ),
        
        'fourth_section_title' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'fourth_section_title' ),
        'fourth_section_description' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'fourth_section_description' ),
        'fourth_section_logos' => $Modulehelper->get_field ( $oc, $modulename, $language_id, 'fourth_section_logos' ),
        
    );
    
    return $this->load->view('extension/module/test_section', $data);
}
}
```

en_gb Language:

```
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']    = 'Test Section';


$_['text_module']      = 'Modules';
$_['text_extension']   = 'Extension';
$_['text_success']     = 'Success: You have modified Test Section module!';
$_['text_edit']        = 'Edit Test Section Module';
```

Model View:

```
    <style>
    
    .hex-mobile-only {
        display: none;
    }
    
    @media(max-width:1023px) {
        .hex-mobile-only {
            display: block;
        }
        
         .hex-mobile-container {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
         }
        
        .hex-mobile-wrap {
            width: calc((100%/3) - 20px);
            height: auto;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
        
        .hex-mobile-wrap img {
            width:100%
        }
        
        .hex-mobile-container .hex-mobile-wrap p {
            font-weight: 600; 
            padding: 20px 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
    
    @media(max-width: 767px) {
        
         .hex-mobile-container {
            display: flex;
            width: 80%;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin: 0 auto;
         }
         
         
        .hex-mobile-wrap {
            width:100%;
            height: auto;
            margin-left: 0px; 
        }
        
        .hex-mobile-wrap img {
            width:100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
      img.hex-img {
        width: 110%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        object-fit: cover;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        position: absolute;
        top: 18px;
        right: -11px
      }

      p.hex-title {
        position: absolute;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        z-index: 99;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #000066 !important;
      }

      .hexagon-gallery {
        margin: auto;
        /*margin-top: 10px;*/
        max-width: 1000px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: 200px;
        grid-gap: 0px;
        padding-left: 50px;
        transform: rotate(270deg);
      }
      
      
      
      @media(max-width: 1024px) {
         .hexagon-gallery { margin: auto;
            margin-top: 80px;
            max-width: 1000px;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
            grid-auto-rows: 200px;
            grid-gap: 0px;
            padding-left: 50px;
            transform: rotate(270deg);
          }
          
          p.hex-title {
            width: 250px;
          }
      }
      
      @media(max-width:1023px) {
          .hexagon-gallery {
              display: none;
          }
      }

      .clip-path {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        width: 220px;
        height: 245px;
        background-color: #424242;
        /*-webkit-clip-path: polygon(*/
        /*  50% 0%,*/
        /*  100% 25%,*/
        /*  100% 75%,*/
        /*  50% 100%,*/
        /*  0% 75%,*/
        /*  0% 25%*/
        /*);*/
        /*clip-path: polygon(*/
        /*  50% 0%,*/
        /*  100% 25%,*/
        /*  100% 75%,*/
        /*  50% 100%,*/
        /*  0% 75%,*/
        /*  0% 25%*/
        /*);*/
        
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon( 50% 1%, 97% 25%, 97% 75%, 50% 99%, 3% 75%, 3% 25% );
        clip-path: polygon(
         50% 1%, 97% 25%, 97% 75%, 50% 99%, 3% 75%, 3% 25%
        );
      }

      .hex:first-child {
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-column: 2 / span 2;
      }

      .hex:first-child p.hex-title {
        left: 89px;
    top: -125px;
      }

      .hex:nth-child(2) {
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-column: 4 / span 2;
      }

      .hex:nth-child(2) p.hex-title {
           right: 290px;
    top: -125px;
      }

      .hex:nth-child(3) {
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-column: 4 / span 2;
      }

      .hex:nth-child(3) .hex-title {
                bottom: -72px;
    left: 508px;
      }

      .hex:nth-child(4) {
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-column: 5 / span 3;
      }

      .hex:nth-child(4) p.hex-title {
        right: 175px;
        bottom: 10px
      }

      .hex:nth-child(5) {
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-column: 3 / span 2;
      }
      
       .hex:nth-child(5) p.hex-title {
        left: 200px;
    bottom: 20px;
      }
      
      @media(max-width: 1024px) {
          
          .hex:first-child p.hex-title {
         left: 89px;
    top: -50px;
      }
      
      .hex:nth-child(2) p.hex-title {
           right: 63px;
    top: -40px;
      }
      
          .hex:nth-child(3) .hex-title {
              bottom: -187px;
    left: 404px;
      }
          
          .hex:nth-child(4) p.hex-title {
        right: -70px;
    bottom: 15px;
      }
          
           .hex:nth-child(5) p.hex-title {
        left: 220px;
    bottom: 15px;
      }
      }
      
     .about-image-info-1:last-child {
         margin-bottom: 0px !important;
     }
     
    </style>
    
    <div class="first-section test-section">
        <h2  data-aos="fade-up"  data-aos-duration="3000"><?= $title; ?></h2>
    
        <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up"  data-aos-easing="linear" data-aos-duration="2500" >
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="abt-main-description">
                    <?= html($first_section_description); ?>
                </div>
            
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?php foreach ($first_section_logos as $logo): ?>
                <div class="about-image">
                    <img src="image/<?= $logo['image']; ?>" alt="logo">
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="second-section">
        <h2  data-aos="fade-up"  data-aos-duration="3000"><?= $second_section_title; ?></h2>
        
        <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up"  data-aos-easing="linear" data-aos-duration="2500" >
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="abt-main-description desc-1">
                    <?= html($second_section_description_1); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="hexagon-gallery">
                    <?php foreach ($second_section_logos as $logo): ?>
                    <div class="hex">
                        <div class="clip-path">
                            <img class="hex-img" src="image/<?= $logo['image']; ?>" alt="<?= $logo['title']; ?>">
                        </div>
                         <p class="hex-title"><?= $logo['title']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>
                
                <div class="hex-mobile-only">
                    <div class="hex-mobile-container">
                    <?php foreach ($second_section_logos as $logo): ?>
                    <div class="hex-mobile-wrap">
                    <img class="" src="image/<?= $logo['image']; ?>" alt="<?= $logo['title']; ?>">
                         <p><?= $logo['title']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="abt-main-description desc-2">
                    <?= html($second_section_description_2); ?>
                </div>
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="third-section">
        <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up"  data-aos-easing="linear" data-aos-duration="2500" >
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img src="image/<?= $third_section_vision_image; ?>" alt="vision logo">
                <h2><?= $third_section_vision_title; ?></h2>
                <div class="grp-description">
                    <?= html($third_section_vision_statement); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img src="image/<?= $third_section_mission_image; ?>" alt="mission logo">
               <h2><?= $third_section_mission_title; ?></h2>
                <div class="grp-description">
                    <?= html($third_section_mission_statement); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2><?= $third_section_value_statement_title; ?></h2>
            </div>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php foreach ($third_section_logos as $key => $logo): 
                if($key % 2 == 1) continue; 
                ?>
                    <div class="about-image-info-1">
                        <div class="about-info">
                            <div class="abt-custom-listings">
                                <?= html($logo['description']); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="about-image">
                                <img src="image/<?= $logo['image']; ?>" alt="logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php foreach ($third_section_logos as $key => $logo): 
                if($key % 2 != 1) continue; 
                ?>
                    <div class="about-image-info-2">
                        <div class="about-image">
                                <img src="image/<?= $logo['image']; ?>" alt="logo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="about-info">
                            <div class="abt-custom-listings">
                                <?= html($logo['description']); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="fourth-section">
            <h2  data-aos="fade-up"  data-aos-duration="3000"><?= $fourth_section_title; ?></h2>
        <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up"  data-aos-easing="linear" data-aos-duration="2500" >
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="abt-main-description">
                    <?= html($fourth_section_description); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php foreach ($fourth_section_logos as $logo): ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="about-image">
                    <img src="image/<?= $logo['image']; ?>" alt="logo">
                     <?= html($logo['description']); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: After you install the module you should refresh modifications, clear cache in admin (blue gear in right upper corner) and in Admin System->Users->User groups set permissions. Please check it all.

Comment: I just set the permission on the user groups https://prnt.sc/4To_PGOrKtNg, but for the caching I unable to find the clear cache button or the modification menu in the dashboard is not appearing. https://prnt.sc/GYes81P5djrY

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are using a "heavy" modified backend!
Try it with a standard installation and all will be displayed.

Comment: ohhh, ok noted on this one. Will have it try again. Thank you for this information.